# Jetpack Compose + Fragment using AndroidViewBinding: how to direct Focus back to side menu from the Fragment?

Tags: android-fragments, android-jetpack-compose, navigation-drawer, android-tv, android-jetpack-compose-tv

I am trying to create an app with Jetpack Compose on Android TV. The app implements a Side Drawer Menu, a Navhost and corresponding routes. One of the routes consists of a Fragment, which I have implemented following:

[Fragments in Compose per official documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/migrate/interoperability-apis/views-in-compose#fragments-in-compose)

The problem is once I navigate and focus on the Fragment, it is not possible to direct the focus back to the Drawer. How could I achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: Could you please add some code to reproduce the issue? Checkout [mre].

Comment: You can do it by listening DPAD events in fragment and then you have to use callbacks which we will move focus to compose part.